# Integrate $\int_0^t e^{sA}e^{sA^T}ds$ when $A$ is invertible but not normal

Tags: integration, matrices, matrix-exponential

So, I tried to use some sort of "integration by parts" method here, but the non-conmutativity of $A$ and $A^T$ doesn't let me reach any further.
I know that $\frac{d}{ds}e^{As}=Ae^{As}$ and, assuming that $A$ is invertible, I also have that$\int e^{As}ds=A^{-1}e^{As}$.

So, I would get something like (I am not so sure about the order thou):
$$\int_0^t e^{sA}e^{sA^T} ds= A^{-1}e^{sA}e^{sA^T}\Big|_0^t-\int_0^t A^{-1}e^{sA}e^{sA^T}A^T ds$$

I see, that the integrals on the left and right are the same but some constants $A^{-1}$ and $A^T$, however since $A^{-1}$ doesn't conmute with $e^{sA^T}$ or $A^{T}$ with $e^{sA}$ I don't see a way where I could factor those constants to determine the integral.

Any ideas on how to proceed, or any alternative methods will e highly appreciated.

Comment: Check "Computing integrals involving the matrix exponential" by van Loan.

Answer (score 3):

Denote the integral by $B$. Then
$$
AB+BA^T=\int_0^t\frac{d}{ds}e^{sA}e^{sA^T}=e^{tA}e^{tA^T}-I.
$$
This is a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation). If no two eigenvalues of $A$ sum to zero, the equation is uniquely solved by $\operatorname{vec}(B)=(I\otimes A+A\otimes I)^{-1}\operatorname{vec}(e^{tA}e^{tA^T}-I)$. (See Wikipedia if you are not familiar with [Kronecker product and vectorisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products).)